# Get hashcode of parent class from inherited class

Tags: c#, inheritance, hashcode

Consider these classes:

```
public class BaseClass {
    public int SomeInt { get; set; }
    public bool SomeBool { get; set; }

    public BaseClass(int i, bool b) {
        SomeInt = i;
        SomeBool = b;
    }
}

public class InheritedClass : BaseClass {
    public List<Int32> SomeInts { get; set; }

    public InheritedClass(int i, bool b, List<Int32> ints): base(i, b) {
        SomeInts = ints;
    }

    public InheritedClass(BaseClass b, List<Int32> ints) : base(b.SomeInt, b.SomeBool) {
        SomeInts = ints;
    }
}
```

And I've got an instance of `InheritedClass`, I want to get the HashCode value of it if it were a `BaseClass`. I've tried casting it:

```
BaseClass x = new BaseClass(10, true);
Console.WriteLine("HashCode x: {0}", x.GetHashCode());
InheritedClass iX = new InheritedClass(x, new List<int> { 1, 2, 3 });
Console.WriteLine("HashCode iX: {0}", iX.GetHashCode());
BaseClass bX = (BaseClass)iX;
//I've also tried:
//BaseClass bX = ix as BaseClass;
Console.WriteLine("Base HashCode bX: {0}", bX.GetHashCode());
```

But the final `WriteLine` is returning the hashcode as if it was an `InhertiedClass`. I can't overide the `GetHashCode` of the `InheritedClass`, and save constructing a new `BaseClass` from the properties of the object, is there anyway to get the HashCode I need?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The hashcode for an instance of anything will be the same no matter how you cast it. Irrespective of how you are 'viewing' it, you are still looking at the same object in memory. The only way I can think of to do this is to clone it as the base type (so you have an actual instance of the base class) and then hash it.

Answer (score 3):

Individual objects have a HashCode.

And as long as you don't override `GetHashCode()`, the value is totally independent of the class (Base or Derived) of the object.

Answer (score 1):

Add this method to InheritedClass:

```
public class InheritedClass : BaseClass {
    public int GetBaseHashCode()
    {
         return base.GetHashCode();
    }
}
```

Then call `iX.GetBaseHashCode();`

**Note:** I'm assuming that you are overriding `GetHashCode()` for `InheritedClass`. Because otherwise these will return exactly the same value.

Answer (score 0):

Since neither of your classes override `GetHashCode` then they'll use the default implementation provided by `System.Object`.

The hashcode is generated for the *object*, so the hashcode generated for `bX` is the same regardless of whether it's treated as the parent class or child class, since the same implementation of `GetHashCode` is used.

If each class had its own `GetHashCode` override then those overrides would be used as you expect when calling `parent.GetHashCode` or `child.GetHashCode` etc.

Answer (score 0):

No, there isn't unless you provide such a method in your inherited class. Just because you cast something doesn't mean it's identity changes. Also, what if you have two instances, that have the same hashcode as the baseclass, but different as the inherited, as a field/property changed?